# Не работает готовый пример с Java Native Access

Tags: java, linux

Нашел на хабрахабре следующий код

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

/** Simple example of native library declaration and usage. */
public class HelloWorld {
    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"), CLibrary.class);
        void printf(String format, Object... args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Запустил в Eclipse и мне выдало листинг ошибок

> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> com.sun.jna.Native.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J
>   at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native
> Method)   at
> com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
>   at
> com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
>   at
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
>   at
> com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
>   at
> HelloWorld$CLibrary.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:8)
>   at
> HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)

Кто-то работал с этой библиотекой? Может что-то не инсталлировано у меня?
Я тестировал в Linux Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: А как бы никого не смущает присутствие в примере вызова msvcrt.dll?
Особенно учитывая, что пробуют запустить его на linux?

Comment: Там же есть выбор нужной библиотеки в зависимости от платформы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы скачивали дистрибутив JNA с [соответствующей страницы](https://github.com/twall/jna/archives/master) на GitHub? Там внутри есть GettingStarted с описанием необходимых системных переменных (jna.library.path, LD_LIBRARY_PATH) - возможно, проблемы именно в них.

Comment: А как добавить в линуксе системные переменные?

Comment: export VAR_NAME=var_value - для текущего сеанса

Comment: спасибо, но я имел ввиду где эту строчечку вставить?

Comment: Если запускаете с консоли, то прямо перед запуском.
Если из IDE - то наверняка в опциях запуска есть возможность настройки переменных среды (в Eclipse есть, например).